# Why value of a state array is not showing in the output in C Program?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm making a C program in which it'll ask full name and address from the user and the program should give output like this:

```
Priya Shah
100,mainstreet
city,subdistrict 
gujarat,382007
```

But program is giving output like this:

```
Priya Shah
100,mainstreet
city,subdistrict
,382007
```

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main(){
        char fname[10],lname[30];
        char house_no[5],street[40],city[30],taluka[20],state[70]="state",pin[6];
        
        printf("Enter your Full Name: ");
        scanf("%s %s",fname,lname);
    
        printf("Enter your Address: (Format of Address is: HouseNo,Street,City,Taluka,State-pin) ");
        scanf("%s %s %s %s %s %s",house_no,street,city,taluka,state,pin);
    
        printf("%s %s\n%s,%s\n%s,%s\n%

s,%s",fname,lname,house_no,street,city,taluka,state,pin);
}
```

I have also initialised the state array then also it is not showing in the output

Comment: `scanf` will write *seven* characters to your six-element `pin` array. Remember that in C strings are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. You need to create space for the null-terminator as well. Going out of bounds of an array leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the exact input you use corresponding to the actual and expected output.

Comment: By the way, *always* check [what `scanf` ***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value)

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question and i would like to tell that every string has a null character which consume one block of space and in your case . you wrote pin[6] and you want enter a pin code , like 110010 it is already 6 character but string automatically add null character so in this case you need to replace pin[6] with pin[7]

thank you.......

Answer (score 0):

`pin[6]` is too short to store 6-character strings like `382007`. A room for terminating null-character is required. It looks like `st` happened to be placed after `pin` and its data is destroyed due to the out-of-range write.

Allocate enough elements and specify the maximum number of characters to read to prevent buffer overrun. Also you should check the return values of `scanf()` to check if it succeeded to read all required things.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char fname[10],lname[30];
    char house_no[5],street[40],city[30],taluka[20],st[70]="state",pin[20];
    
    printf("Enter your Full Name: ");
    if (scanf("%9s %29s",fname,lname) != 2){
        fputs("read error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter your Address: (Format of Address is: HouseNo,Street,City,Taluka,State-pin) ");
    if(scanf("%4s %39s %29s %19s %69s %19s",house_no,street,city,taluka,st,pin) != 6){
        fputs("read error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%s %s\n%s,%s\n%s,%s\n%s,%s",fname,lname,house_no,street,city,taluka,st,pin);
}
```